# Predict change in variable

Tags: regression, time-series, forecasting

Probably this is easy to answer, but let me formulate the question: If we have a variable $Y_t$ measured over time and cross-sectionally, and we calculate the change of this variable from $t-1$ to $t$, let's call it $\Delta Y_t$. Next, we want to predict this $\Delta Y_t$ at time $t$ using several predictors (let's call them $a$ and $b$ for simplicity). My question is as follows: Can we use $a$ and $b$ at time $t-1$, or do they need to be measured at $t-2$? I am asking because $\Delta Y_t$ also contains information from period $t-1$ (logically, as it is the change from $t-1$ to $t$), so does that lead to any problems in the regression model?

Answer (score -1):

Before trying any modeling with time series, it is important to make sure that time-series you have is **stationary**.
In simple words, it means that, if you select random **consecutive** sample sizes of `n` from this time-series they will have equal covariances. One considers time series purely stationary if and only if it complies to the following:

1. Constant mean
2. Constant variance
3. Constant covariance between equally sized periods.

Stationarity is one of the assumptions of regression models.

Edit: Formatting

Comment: Stationarity is a *simplifying assumption* used in *many* time series models--but not all.  (Consider [GARCH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_conditional_heteroskedasticity), for instance.) This misses the point of the question, which concerns the issue of [previsibility](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=previsibility+stochastic+process).

Comment: thanks for the reply, but that does not answer my question yet as indicated by @whuber.